# Jenkins builds all branch in same name but different branch type

Tags: git, jenkins, branch

I have a Repo in Bitbucket which is having Branch names as follows

- `master`
- `feature/master`
- `bug/master`
- `release/master`

In my Jenkins configuration, Branch Specifier is configured as */master.

I am expecting my Jenkins to build only the master branch. But it is building all branches which have the name 'master' in it (`feature/master`, `bug/master`, `release/master`)

How can I ignore the other three branches to build (`feature/master`, `bug/master`, `release/master`)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing something, but what I understand is that you are using pattern `"*/master"` where `"master"` is enough and will match only `"master"` branch.

Hope this helps

Regards